# How to create a store which encodes the default params to JSON and not HTTP parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I want my store's request payload look like this:

```
{"start":0,"limit":10,"sort":"BIRTH_PLACE","dir":"ASC"}
```

with Ajax request using jsonData it works:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'bank/admin/listUsers',
        jsonData: request,
        success : function(response, options) {
            console.log('Response:', response);
            console.log('Options:', options);
            var reply = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            console.log('Reply:', reply);
        }
    });
```

but width the store my request payload looks like this:

```
start=0&limit=10&sort=username&dir=ASC
```

Comment: Use a [*json writer*](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json) in your store definition.

Comment: I tried but now in the posts i see that the parameters (start, limit, sort nad dir) are in the Form data:

Form Data:
start:0
limit:10
sort:username
dir:ASC
xaction:read

Comment: Extjs allways sends these values as query parameters. If you want to change that behaviour, you'll probably have to write your own writer and/or proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that something like this works. Just make your store's proxy populate the `jsonData` property with the contents of `params`.

```
Ext.define('MyProxy', {
    alias: 'myproxy',
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',

    getMethod: function(request) 
    {
        return 'POST';
    },

    buildRequest: function(operation) 
    {
        var request = this.callParent(arguments);
        request.jsonData = request.params;
        request.params = {};
        return request;
    },
});
```